# AWS ECS spawn a Docker container from the running one

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

Looking for the ways to implement the following scenario:

1. Deploy a Docker image into AWS ECS. This container runs as a REST service and accepts external requests (I already know how to do that).
2. Upon the request, execute code in the running container that pulls another Docker image from the external repo and deploys into the same ECS cluster as a single run container that exits upon completion.
3. (Bonus) the dynamic cluster needs to access some EC2 private IP within the same AWS console login.

The logic on the running container is written in Python so I wonder if I should use boto3 lib to do what I need to do?

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.start_task

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at that, seems to be the way to go. Am still looking for practical gotchas, hints, etc